# I am having issues using the mapquest GeoJson implementation in Node/Express. Getting an error " body used already"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use the mapquest API and I followed the documentation but I am getting an error saying :
HttpError: body used already for: https://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=

here is my geoCoder.js setup:

```
const NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

const options = {
  provider: process.env.GEOCODER_PROVIDER,
//   fetch: customFetchImplementation,
  httpAdapter: 'https',
  apiKey: process.env.GEOCODER_API_KEY,
  formatter: null
};

const geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

module.exports = geocoder
```

and here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const geocoder = require('../utils/geocoder')


const HomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    homeId: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a home ID'],
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        maxlength: [10, 'Home ID must be less than 10 characters']
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an address']
    },
    location: {
        type: {
          type: String, 
          enum: ['Point'], 
        },
        coordinates: {
          type: [Number],
          index: '2dsphere'
        },
        formattedAddress: String
      },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

// Geocode & create location
HomeSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const loc = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
    // console.log(loc)
    this.location = {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [loc[0].longitude, loc[0].latitude],
        formattedAddress: loc[0].formattedAddress
    }

    // Do not save address
    this.address = undefined
    next()
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Home', HomeSchema)
```

and here is the controller that handles the request:

```
exports.addHome = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
    //    console.log(req.body)
    const home = await Home.create(req.body)
    return res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        data: home
    })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        if(error.code === 11000) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'This home already exists.'})
        }
        res.status(500).json({error: 'Server error here!'})
    }
}
```

any ideas on why this is not working as expected? the first request that I made in postman was successful but everything after that failed.

Comment: https://github.com/nchaulet/node-geocoder/issues/340

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to actually be the fact that my mapquest account was out of transactions. I created a new account to get a new key with no code changes and it worked.

Comment: how did you find out that you were out of transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove
httpAdaptor: 'https',
from the options and it should work